# How PHP return value fetch from flutter

Tags: php, flutter

I have this simple php file

```
<?php

$arrA = array("name" => "Adam", "age" => "25");

$jasonValue =json_encode($arrA);
return $jasonValue;
```

i was wondering is there a way to fetch this return value as a json code in flutter? output should be like

```
{"name":"Adam", "age":"25"}
```

Here is waht i did but it did not work

```
 var url = Uri.http('path_to_my_php_file.php');
 var response = await http.get(url);    

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {       
       Map data = json.decode(response.body);
       print(data);
    } else {
      print('Something wents wrong');
    }
```

Comment: You should be echoing the JSON, not returning it. `return` has to be inside a function.

Comment: there is no other way to get the return value?

Comment: `return` is used in functions, the caller gets it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use https, it's useless because streamResponse is used in http flutter. For example:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as https;
import 'dart:convert';

Future<void> _fetchData() async {
    var url = Uri.parse('path_to_my_php_file.php');
    final response = await https.get(url);    
    
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var body = json.decode(response.body);
      print(body);
    } else {
      print("Something went wrong");
    }
}
```

or http

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

Future<void> _fetchData() async {
  var url = Uri.http('path_to_my_php_file.php');
  var request = http.Request('GET', url);

  http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
  }else {
    print(response.reasonPhrase);
  }
}
```

Comment: it only works for echo, not for return

Comment: Hi there, it's only example. But i edited now.

Comment: Not working bro
 
      var url = Uri.http('ip', '/phpfile.php');
      var request = http.Request('GET', url);
      http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

Comment: Edit url like this Uri.parse('${ip}/phpfile.php');

Comment: Background concurrent copying GC freed 16937(1818KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 1946KB/3MB, paused 38.888ms total 92.045ms this is the output

Comment: that's working, now we need get body from response.streambytesToString()

Answer (score 0):

You can't `return` the `json`, you can only get the json by using `echo`

**In PHP**

```
<?php

    $arrA = array("name" => "Adam", "age" => "25");
    
    $jasonValue =json_encode($arrA);
    echo $jasonValue;
    return $jasonValue;
?>
```

**In Flutter**

Just use [http: ^0.13.4](https://pub.dev/packages/http)

```
final response = await http.post(url, body: body);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
   final body = json.decode(response.body);
   print(body.toString);
}
```

**Output :**

```
  {
     "name":"Adam",
      "age":"25"
   }
```

Comment: How does this help if the PHP script doesn't echo the JSON?

Comment: yeah i don't wanna echo, i wanna get the return value if possible

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
return $jasonValue;
```

to

```
echo $jasonValue;
```

in the PHP script. `echo` is how output is sent to the client, return values are not sent on the network (unless the caller of the function does that).

Comment: there is no way to get the returned value?

Comment: You already asked that and I answered it. No.